# Is $VV^T + D$ a submanifold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, differential-geometry, manifolds, compact-manifolds

If the positive definite matrix P forms a manifold,  is that the subset that {P: P = V V^T + D} where V is a low rank matrix  and D is a positive definite matrix a sub-manifold?

This idea is corresponding to an application in finance that P is covariance matrix and V is a factor structure.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you mean $P$ forms a manifold?

Comment: @Berci: Possibly he means that the _set_ of all positive definite matrices form a submanifold of the space of all $n\times n$ matrices.

Answer (score 2):

What a coincidence. Someone asked a closely related (but different) [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/343996/is-this-subset-of-positive-definite-symmetric-matrices-closed#comment739390_343996) just two days ago.

Let $k\le n$ be a positive integer. Note that the five sets
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{P}&=\{P\in M_n(\mathbb{R}): P \text{ is positive definite}\},\\
\mathcal{S}_1&=\{D+VV^T: D\in\mathcal{P},\, V\in M_n(\mathbb{R}),\, \operatorname{rank} V\le k\},\\
\mathcal{S}_2&=\{D+VV^T: D\in\mathcal{P},\, V\in M_n(\mathbb{R}),\, \operatorname{rank} V=k\},\\
\mathcal{S}_3&=\{D+VV^T: D\in\mathcal{P},\, V\in M_{n,k}(\mathbb{R}),\, \operatorname{rank} V\le k\},\\
\mathcal{S}_4&=\{D+VV^T: D\in\mathcal{P},\, V\in M_{n,k}(\mathbb{R}),\, \operatorname{rank} V=k\},\\
\end{align*}
are ***identical*** to each other. So, whatever properties does $\mathcal{P}$ possess, those $\mathcal{S}_j$s possess the same properties too.